# LinkedIn API post to moderated group results in [status code] 403 [reason phrase] Forbidden

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to post to a moderated LinkedIn group via their API but I only get a 403 answer back, with a reason phrase "Forbidden".

I can use the same code to post to profiles, company pages and even non-moderated groups, so why are moderated groups any different? There's nothing about it in the API docs and I can't find anything anywhere else.

The endpoint I'm using is this:

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/[group_id]/posts?format=json&oauth2_access_token=[my_token]

Anyone has any idea what could be the problem and how I can post to the group? Or is it impossible to post to a moderated LinkedIn group via their API?

Answer (score -3):

"Forbidden" means you are not allowed to access that URL, and it's not because of missing authentication. In other words, it's not going to work.

Comment: Fair enough, I know what forbidden means, but then how do I post to that group? Or is it impossible to post to a moderated LinkedIn group via their API?

Comment: Wow, what a totally useless response.  Nice job @gnasher729